# When new content db added to web application , can not see the spcontent user in new database permissions?

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search

I have a domain account spcontent for default content access account
- i created a web application with a content db and assigned full read permissions to spcontent user and when i check database permissions for content database it has spdataaccess permissions

- but when i add new content db to same web application i can not see the spcontent user in new database permissions?

Comment: What is your question or what problem are you encountering?

Comment: as i said after i add new content db there is no sql permissions added for default content access acout

Comment: And what issue is this causing? Do you have an error message? ULS log file?